# riot.js: Listen for events of another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, riot.js

Let's say I have two custom elements: a and b.
a contains another element that can be clicked and I want to trigger a custom event when this happens. That custom event should then be caught by element b.

I can use this.trigger in element a, but this.on in element b doesn't catch the event (which seems logical, since it wasn't triggered on b).

So: Can I retrieve element a in element b to do something like "elementA.on()" in element b?

Basically, I want functionality like RiotControl, but without storing the data, since I just want to trigger a modal in my use case and not store anything.

I could probably fall back to jQuery and trigger and listen for events on document, but is this really a good way?

Comment: Can you not create the event handler in a parent component that wraps both A and B? That way the result can be passed to both elements.

Comment: I would prefer to not change my html structure just so events can be triggered/received, because I think it is good the way it is right now, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Do you need to modify the html to do so? You should be able to create a wrapper component that does not add any elements.

Comment: But if I create a wrapper component I modify the html, or what exactly do you mean? :/

Answer (score 3):

You can create a shared observable e.g:

```
var eventBus = riot.observable();
```

When you mount your elements you can pass it as an option:

```
riot.mount('elementa', { eventBus: eventBus })
riot.mount('elementb', { eventBus: eventBus })
```

Then they can listen and trigger on the same observable:

```
this.opts.eventBus.trigger('openModal', ...maybeSomeOptions);
this.opts.eventBus.on('openModal', function(...maybeSomeOptions) {});
```

Disclaimer: riotjs is new to me

Comment: Thanks, seems like a nice workaround. But I have to change my mounts to manually include each tag (previously I could use '*') for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

The way I tackled this was to use a mixin to automatically include the same Observable into multiple tags.

```
// mixins.js
let ObservableMixin = {
    observable: riot.observable()
};
```

Then in any .tag file where I wanted the shared observable to live, I would simply call.

```
// Any .tag file
this.mixin(ObservableMixin);
...
this.observable.trigger('eventName', { optional: options });
```

For more information about mixins check out: [Riot Mixins](http://riotjs.com/guide/#mixins)

Comment: A "global mixin" may also be useful to some people: http://riotjs.com/guide/#mixins (scroll down the "Global mixins" section)

Comment: Yes, this mixin is in fact global, I've just named it according to the problem it's trying to solve in this example.  It can be called 'globalMixin' or whatever you prefer.

Comment: @lupor did you try the above?